# How do I use a variable with an ex command?

Tags: vimscript, command-line, arithmetic

I wrote a moderately complex routine for Vim and I need to programmatically set the height of windows.

The way to do this is with `:resize [N]` as the help says.

But my invocation didn't work until I employed `exec`:

```
exe `resize `.i[1]
```

The following doesn't work, it always resizes to a height of 1 instead of the required `i[1]`:

```
resize i[1]
```

So I understand that `resize` takes a Number type and I am apparently feeding it a string, but I can't figure out how to avoid `exec`.

Maybe there's a trick I can use to use the `+` operator with `0`? In fact the Vim doc explicitly tells us to do this.

I tried it, but it doesn't work! It works with `echo` but not `res`.

Then I tried setting the value `i[1] + 0` to a variable and then using that. Indeed it seems that when I use `res`, it does not attempt to expand the value of variables. Really perplexing.

Is there another canonical fast way to convert an integer string into a Number? Perhaps some other thing is causing this unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use a variable directly with `:res`. Compare the help text for [`:res`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/window.txt.html#%3Ares), [`:s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute), `:echo` and [`:exe`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute):

```
:res[ize] -N                                    :res :resize CTRL-W_-
CTRL-W -        Decrease current window height by N (default 1).
```

---

```
:[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]
                        For each line in [range] replace a match of {pattern}
                        with {string}.
                        For the {pattern} see pattern.
                        {string} can be a literal string, or something
                        special; see sub-replace-special.
```

---

```
                                                        :ec :echo
:ec[ho] {expr1} ..      Echoes each {expr1}, with a space in between.  The
                        first {expr1} starts on a new line.
                                                        :exe :execute
:exe[cute] {expr1} ..   Executes the string that results from the evaluation
                        of {expr1} as an Ex command.
```

---

The text uses `expr1` for `echo` and `exe`, but nothing of the sort for the other commands. For `:s`, it's specially stated that the replacement can be [something special](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special):

```
                                        sub-replace-special :s\=
When the {string} starts with "\=" it is evaluated as an expression, see
sub-replace-expression.  You can use that for complex replacement or special
characters.
```

In short, unless the command is expected to be followed by an *expression*, don't expect variables to evaluated.

`:exe` is the way to go, in this case.

---

By the way, you don't need to use `.` here, the following will work the same:

```
:exe 'resize' i[1]
```

`exe` implicitly joins arguments with spaces. It's when you *don't* want the sapce that you should use `.` with `exe` arguments.